# Types of version control systems

Tags: version-control, git

On the topic of Git; are there other types of version control systems?

other than **Local VCS**, **Centralized VCS** and **Distributed VCS** stated in [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Local", "centralized" and "distributed" are synonymous with "here", "there" and "both", respectively.

[image]

The only thing that is neither here nor there, is nowhere. So I guess the only other type of version control is "Non-Existent VCS" which, unfortunately, is still quite prevalent in the industry.

Comment: You could argue that VSS is a "nowhere" system...

Answer (score 2):

Local VCS, Centralized VCS and Distributed VCS are various ways to set up version control infrastructure.  Git specifically is a distributed version control system where every client contains an entire history of the project.

Team Foundation Server and Subversion are examples of a centralized version control system, where a central server contains the history and each client only contains the latest files.

There are many many many other source control software packages which all fall into one of the 3 categories, just like cars can fall into manual and automatic transmissions.